# Can I use Angular Dev Tools in Chrome on an iFrame that is cross-origin?

Tags: angular, iframe, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I have the Angular Dev tools Chrome Extension. It works fine on the top level page, but not on an iframed Angular page. In my case I want to use the dev tools only to look at the iframe content. The iframe will always be coming from a different domain then the top level page.

It will be ok if the solution only works when the iframed page is a localhost, but preferably from any cross-origin domain.